# How to show website in only one country Google

Tags: seo, google-search, squarespace

My client has 3 websites, each has it's region.

```
eu.ralphkerlesart.com - for Europe countries
us.ralphkerlesart.com - for USA and Canada
ralphkerlesart.com - for other regions
```

I need only one website display in each region - the one that fits it. For now the website for other regions also show up in USA together with US website. Also, website without subdomain is the only website that appear in google search in Europe, and European website doesn't display anywhere at all.

These websites were created with squarespace, and all regional settings there are done. I also add all websites in google search console and connected them with USA, UK and Australia. But it doesn't help.

For now I made some coding to check the ip of the user and redirect him on website that fits his region.

Is there any way to display only one website in each region?

Comment: "check the ip of the user and redirect him" - what about search engines / Google?

Answer (score 2):

Finally it is Google decision, where to rank a website. What do you could do:

- create for every country subdomain an own Search Console property and bind it to certain country. The country binding can be done in the old GSC, under https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/i18n.
- Another hint, which lies in your hand: use `hreflang`. On this way you send clear signal to Google about language and country orientation of each and every url.

Comment: The OP states they have already done your first point: "I also add all websites in google search console and connected them with USA, UK and Australia."

Answer (score 2):

Google uses hreflang tags to match the user's language preference to the right variation of your pages.

The hreflang attribute on each page should include a reference to itself as well as to all the pages that serve as alternates for it. The hreflang attributes for your homepage might look like this:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://eu.ralphkerlesart.com" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://us.ralphkerlesart.com" hreflang="en-us" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://ralphkerlesart.com" hreflang="en" />
```

I.E. if you targeting English speakers in Canada it would be "en-ca" whereas targeting English speakers in the UK would be "en-gb". But when targeting English speakers in all 27 (?) EU nations at once then you would just use "en".

The "content" attribute is comprised of a 2-letter ISO 639 language code, followed by a dash and the appropriate ISO 3166 geography code. For example:

```
de-at: German, Austria
de-de: German, Germany
en-us: English, United States
es-ar: Spanish, Argentina
```

Hreflang Tag

https://moz.com/learn/seo/hreflang-tag

How To Tell Bing Your Website's Country and Language

https://blogs.bing.com/webmaster/2011/03/01/how-to-tell-bing-your-websites-country-and-language/

International Targeting report

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6059209

Comment: Using `hreflang="en"` for both "Europe" _and_ the "rest of the world" does not help to differentiate these two regions. The [Wikipedia article on ISO 3166-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) states that you can use the _reserved_ code `EU` for the European Union. The country codes are uppercase by convention.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make the the change shown below to all properties of your website to ensure SEO.

In Google Search Console (previously known as Webmaster Tools), for the selected property, you have to set international targeting as shown in the this screenshot:

[image: GWT - International Targeting]

Comment: You can use this URL: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/i18n?hl=en&siteUrl=https://www.perferreddomain.com/&authuser=2&tid=geo

Comment: Also as suggested by @Group of Oceninfo, using hreflangs is a good practice. Once you get to the page I have suggested you, you can configure accordingly.

Comment: The OP states they have already done this: "I also add all websites in google search console and connected them with USA, UK and Australia."

Comment: You have to make sure you add all properties (http://example.com, https://example.com, http://www.example.com, https://www.example.com) to make sure everything is set alright.

Answer (score -3):

Use geolocation or iplocation features and wisely make use of backends to control acessibility of the page.

Comment: Could you provide more detail? This "answer" is too vague.

Comment: Such a short answer is not high quality.   I better answer would provide instructions, and link to references.